# How to Compile Ncurses Program for Native Windows Use

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, ncurses, msys2

I'm trying to compile a C program using Ncurses on Windows. I compiled it successfully using GCC and it works perfectly if I run it in Cygwin or MSYS2. However, if I try to run it in the Windows Command Prompt, I get this error:

> Error opening terminal: xterm-256color.

Is it possible to compile it to run using the native Windows console? This is how I've been compiling it:

> gcc -o PROGRAMNAME main.c -lncurses

I also have the Cygwin and Msys dlls for Ncurses copied into the directory of the compiled executable.

**Update**

So I figured out how to get the program to run. I deleted all the DLLs from the project folder and then added "C:\msys64\usr\bin" to my PATH environment variable. However, I would still like to know if there's a way to get this to work if I were to distribute it, since it's still relying on my installation of MSYS2.

**Update 2**

Gave up and just used pdcurses and it works fine.

**Update 3**

Nevermind, found a solution! See below.

Comment: That's done using the MinGW configuration, mentioned in the [`INSTALL`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/INSTALL#L750) file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I decided to use pdcurses since it would probably save me more headaches to just use an existing library designed for Windows rather than build ncurses from source for the same purpose.

Comment: MinGW's provided it as a package over the past few years.  None of MinGW, msys2 or Cygwin has a comprehensive set of packages, so developers generally build their own.

Comment: [This query](https://packages.msys2.org/search?t=binpkg&q=ncurses) indicates that msys2 does provide a package for the MinGW configurations.

Comment: An update in case you were curious. It turns out I didn't have the Mingw_w64 toolchain for MSYS2 installed. The Mingw_w64 package for ncurses also installs its header files in /include/ncurses/ instead of just /include/, so the scripts I was using couldn't find them. Installing the toolchain, plus including the ncurses directory during compilation, plus statically linking some libraries the executable couldn't find seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out a solution. I'll post it here in case anyone else has this same issue. Thanks to Thomas Dickey for your help!

1. Install the [mingw-w64 toolchain](https://packages.msys2.org/group/mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain) and any other packages you need to compile your project (this is mostly where I messed up)
2. Make sure to include the /mingw64/include/ncurses directory when compiling, or else gcc won't be able to find curses.h
3. Include /mingw64/bin as a static directory or copy over the necessary dlls to the same folder as the directory

I ended up with this to compile:

```
gcc -I/mingw64/include/ncurses -o PROGRAMNAME main.c -lncurses -L/mingw64/bin -static
```

Comment: The above command did not work for me on "MSYS2 MinGW x64". Here here is how I modified it to get it going: `gcc -I/mingw64/include/ncurses -o hello hello.c -lncurses -L/mingw64/bin -DNCURSES_STATIC`

Comment: @Laszlo do you need any DLLs in that same folder in order for it to work? Don't you need the `-static` argument as well?

Comment: No I do not need it. Despite not specifying the `-static` flag it seem that linkage happens statically or I do not know. This: `-DNCURSES_STATIC` is equal to a `#define NCURSES_STATIC 1` in the code. After the build I can run the code even from Windows `cmd.exe` too (for "MSYS2 MinGW x64" prompt I need extra tricks to emulate the xterm, but it runs too).